# Problem uploading service for Silverlight SQL connection

Tags: silverlight

I've found a very small sample showing Silverlight SQL connection (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/CntDbSlght.aspx), I've tested it and it works fine on local system, also I've changed its connection string so that it shows data from my remote database, but when I upload files to my host, I cannot see any SQL data, it seems that something is broken, how should I configure my web.config?

What are CrossDomain.XML and ClientAccessPolicy.XML files? should I upload them? If so, where should they be? How should I bind my service? what am I doing wrong? I click on VS2010 publish (in build menu) and select file system, then I upload all files existing in this folder, I use C#.

Comment: I think my servicereference.clientconfig file is a source of problem, as it points to localhost:->        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1351/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
how should I correct it? how should I update this file? should I upload this file separately?

Comment: I've changed localhost:1351... to http://www.mydomain.com/service1.svc, but now when trying to run it from local host get following error:An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://www.mydomain.com/Service1.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent..... , what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to access an external Silverlight web service from your local dev environment you certainly need a ClientAccessPolicy.XML file on the website. This tells the site services where requests can come from (normally only from the same site the SL app was run from).

Your ClientAccessPolicy.XML file needs to go into the actual root of your website i.e. 'mydomain.com/ClientAccessPolicy.XML.

**Note: You do not also need a CrossDomain.XML if you have ClientAccessPolicy (which is the SL specific one).* CrossDomain.xml is an older flash compatibility file that sometimes exists on sites.

Comment: thanks, but how should I change my servicereference.clientconfig file? how should I point to my service?

Comment: It sounds like you already changed your config to point at the service. If you need more detail I suggest you add your config to the question. Guess-work takes longer :)